# localize data annotations default messages ([Required] [StringLength] etc.)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, data-annotations

if I decorate the properties of my ViewModels with attributes like this:

```
public class Vm
{

[Required]
[StringLength(35)]
public string Name {get;set;}

}
```

I am going to get english validation messages:

```
"this field is required"
"The field Name must be a string with a maximum length of 35"
```

how could I translate them ?

Comment: I described my approach here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398691/mvc-localisation-from-the-database-that-covers-all-messages-required-displayna

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could use the [`ErrorMessageResourceName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessageresourcename.aspx) property:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "SomeResource")]
[StringLength(30, ErrorMessageResourceName = "SomeOtherResource")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

You may checkout [this blog post](http://helios.ca/2010/02/17/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation-with-localization/) for an example.

---

UPDATE:

In `Application_Start`:

```
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "Messages";
```

And in the `Messages.resx` file you need to add the custom error messages. Use Reflector to look at the `System.Web.Mvc` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` assemblies in order to see the key names to use.

Comment: I would like to change the default messages without specifying it for each property, I saw once that you have to have a Messages.resx in your App_GlobalResources, but I don't know the keys for each message

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov could you please tell me more exactly where in System.Web.Mvc to look

Comment: Oh I see. You are trying to localize the default error messages. I afraid this is not possible unless you install a localized version of the .NET framework. I would recommend you specifying the error message in each attribute and have a custom resources file handling those messages.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov no, your update was what I needed, I want to localize the validation messages, you showed me once one key PropertyValueInvalid, all I need to know now is where in System.Web.Mvc to find all these keys

Comment: @Omu, what I showed you works only for some special things that are handled by ASP.NET MVC and not DataAnnotations like PropertyValueInvalid which is used for example when trying to bind a string to an integer value which is not of the correct format. You cannot do this with other messages like Required because they are handled by the DataAnnotations framework.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov this is what you showed me that time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156488/localize-default-model-validation-in-mvc-2 and it works, I thought that there could be some more keys in there to use for translation

Comment: Omu: did you find the other keys?

Comment: Is there an equivalent parameter for `[Display]` or do we simply avoid using `labelfor` and place the `@Resource` references in the views instead?

Comment: ,ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages)) also needs to be specified in mvc 5

Answer (score 10):

There is a much better solution using asp.net MVC 3 these days incase someone is looking for a newer and far better approach.

http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/easy-model-and-validation-localization-in-asp-net-mvc3/

For example:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.LocalizedStrings))]
    [LocalizedDisplayName(ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserId", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.LocalizedStrings))]
    [LocalizedDescription(ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserIdDescription", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.LocalizedStrings))]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

SO related question -
[Mvc 3.0 DataAnnotations Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536372/mvc-3-0-dataannotations-localization)