# Mvc 3.0 DataAnnotations Localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, razor, data-annotations

Thre's a number of post on StackOverflow as well as other sites around this topic. I was however having hard time finding anything related to MVC3 and it's specific resource keys.

In order to globally localize generic MVC messages one should:

- Create a resource file under App_GlobalResources folder
- set DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey to the resource name (without .resx)
- Create localized copies of MvcResources.resx under that folder and resource name

I've tested this and according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultmodelbinder.resourceclasskey%28v=vs.98%29.aspx), if I set the ResourceClassKey to something non existent it should throw exception. It doesn't happen so I must be doing something wrong.

If anyone has got this working under MVC3 and Razor, here's the questions:

- where to find the correct MvcResources.resx for MVC3? I was only able to find one for version 2
- Where should one set the DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey property? Would that be under Global.asax -> Application_Start or for each request?

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to solve it in that way or do you want something easier? http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/easy-model-and-validation-localization-in-asp-net-mvc3/

Comment: @Jonas: great article! didn't know that was possible!

Comment: I want the right way :) And this way seems easier in the long run. There will potentially be many, many screens that need global localization on messages and I want the set once, forget about it approach.

Comment: Sorry jgauffin. I posted a comment before I read your approach. Seems promising. Will give it a try on Monday. And I'm glad we agree on on the "don't do that" part.

Comment: I've tested the Griffin.MvcContrib library and the approach seems very appealing. However, there seems to be a problem when Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture is changed dynamically after application startup. Because in Application_Start one would register a specific resource manager it would appear the approach only works for when application is localized only to one specific language - not when it supports multiple languages (cultures) and allows users to change it. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Got it to work properly. Programmer error, as usual - one of the resource files was set as Content instead of Embedded Resource. Can you please add a formal answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

> where to find the correct MvcResources.resx for MVC

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Comment: the link is now obsolete