# asp.net mvc validation must be a number custom error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I am new to asp.net and I have a problem. When the users insert in a editor for a decimal field something other than numbers, they get an error "Field name" is not a number. But I don't want them to receive this message I want them to receive another message. I have no problem with this with required and range validators.
Is there any way for me to do this?

I am not refering necessarily to changing the culture just displaying another message.

Thanks.

Comment: Post your validation attrbiure here for reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the actual answer:

Create a class `CustomClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider`. Copy the code from the MVC sources. Change the method `MakeErrorString` to output the appropiate message like this:

```
private static string MakeErrorString(string displayName)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
        Core.Resources.Errors.EroareNuENr, 
        displayName);
}
```

I couldn't find a way not to copy the code just extend it as it uses this static method.
If anyone knows this please tell me.

Then, in global.asax, I wrote this:

```
var cdProvider = ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.SingleOrDefault(p => p.GetType().Equals(typeof(ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider)));
            if(cdProvider != null)
            {
                ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Remove(cdProvider);
                ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(
                        new CustomClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider());
            }
```

so that the flow would actually be routed to my class and not the class in the asp.net MVC dll

I got the idea from [here](http://jwwishart.blogspot.com/2011/03/custom-server-and-client-side-required.html):

Answer (score 13):

Hope I understand your, to change `RangeValidator` `ErrorMessage` just initialize `ErrorMessage` parameter:

```
[Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "Some another error message insert here!")]
[RegularExpression("\d", ErrorMessage = "!!!")]
public decimal DecimalField { get; set; }
```

Comment: no, I can modify the errormessage for the range validator just fine but if the user inserts "abc" in the field for example I get a different kind of error message. The range error in this case gets displayed if he inputs 101 for example.

Comment: I think RegularExpression validator will help your. Check my answer above.

Comment: [DisplayName("Diameter")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9,\.]+$", ErrorMessage = "Error msg")]
        public decimal? ExternamDiameter { get; set; }

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is is not a trivial task.  However you can try the following hack...
Better to do this only on essential fields, as this is more code to maintain.

In the controller's action method

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
  // code
}
else
{
  if (ModelState["YourField"].Errors.Count > 0)
  {
    ModelState["YourField"].Errors.Clear(); 
    ModelState.AddModelError("YourField", "Your custom message here");
  }

  // code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `ResourceClassKey` of ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider class to name of a global resource that contains `FieldMustBeNumeric` key to replace mvc validation error message of number with your custom message. Also key of date validation error message is `FieldMustBeDate`.

```
ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey="MyResources"; // MyResource is my global resource
```

See here for more details on how to add the `MyResources.resx` file to your project:

[The field must be a number. How to change this message to another language?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18392437/114029)

Answer (score 1):

To change the error message you get after server side validation you need to change 'PropertyValueInvalid' key in your resource file and assign the resource file name to `DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey`. See this question for details: [localize default model validation in mvc 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156488/localize-default-model-validation-in-mvc-2/3156814#3156814)

Answer (score 1):

Look for solution at the end of this page:

http://jwwishart.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/custom-server-and-client-side-required-validator-in-mvc-2-using-jquery-validate/

I checked this in my MVC 3 RTM project and it works well.

Comment: Updated link - http://jwwishart.blogspot.com/2011/03/custom-server-and-client-side-required.html

Answer (score 1):

... or [use jQuery to change to message on the client](http://greenicicleblog.com/2011/02/28/fixing-non-localizable-validation-messages-with-javascript/).

Comment: I've tried this and it works nicely. I find it preferable to changing an MVC3 source file

Answer (score 1):

A quick and simple hack for Customize **RangeValidator** **ErrorMessage** --"'Field name' is not a number"-- is using RegularExpression

```
[Range(0.5, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Amount should be in range {1} to {2}.")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[RegularExpression(@"\d", ErrorMessage = "Amount is not valid.")]
public decimal Amount{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own custom validation attribute: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems that since Para's answer MVC evolved and now the ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider accepts a ResourceClassKey property. It uses the FieldMustBeNumeric and FieldMustBeNumeric messages specified in your resource class.