# The field must be a number. How to change this message to another language?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, localization, numbers, data-annotations

How can I change that messages for all `int` fields so that instead of saying:

`The field must be a number` in English, it shows:

`El campo tiene que ser numerico` in Spanish.

Is there are a way?

Comment: when you want show this message ?

Comment: in really change the English message for spanish message will be the goal

Comment: sorry i want to show that message when in the texbox thas is model.int somebody write string on it, with  jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive show that message in english (I need to that message is in spanish for all my int field)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you happen to be using ASP.NET MVC 4 onwards, check this post:

[Localizing Default Error Messages in ASP.NET MVC and WebForms](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2013/03/31/localizing-default-error-messages-in-asp-net-mvc-and-web-form.aspx)

Basically you have to add the following piece of code in your `Application_Start()` method in `Global.asax`:

```
 ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "Messages";
 DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "Messages";
```

Right click your ASP.NET MVC project in Solution Explorer inside Visual Studio and select `Add => Add ASP.NET Folder => App_GlobalResources`.

Now add a `.resx` file inside this folder called `Messages.resx`.

Finally add the following string resources in that `.resx` file:

```
Name                   Value
====                   =====
FieldMustBeDate        The field {0} must be a date.
FieldMustBeNumeric     The field {0} must be a number.
PropertyValueInvalid   The value '{0}' is not valid for {1}.
PropertyValueRequired  A value is required.
```

You should be good to go.

Note that the value you're interested in is the `FieldMustBeNumeric`. To localize it to *Spanish*, you have to add another resource file named `Messages.es.resx`. In this specific `.resx` file replace the resource value with:

```
Name                Value
====                =====
FieldMustBeNumeric  El campo {0} tiene que ser numerico.
```

---

If you happen to be using ASP.NET MVC 3 downwards, this solution can help you achieve the same result: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2551481/114029

Comment: @ivowiblo: really... What's the problem you get? Maybe I can help you.

Comment: ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider doesn't have a ResourceClassKey property. That's the problem in MVC3, it has the texts in a hardcoded resource file and they fixed it in MVC4.

Comment: @ivowiblo I see... for old versions of ASP.NET MVC I think I used this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2551481/114029 I'll update my answer to make this clear up front.

Comment: After a long search this answer helped me. I was confused between Javascript validation and the *unobstrusive* validation, which uses the `data-val-number` HTML5 attribute. Thank you.

Comment: I am getting the word in {0} in English and the rest is coming up from the translation. How do we translate the Field as well ?

Comment: Field is not translated (by resource files or anything), but can be easily changed by adding [Display(Name = "YourText")].

Comment: But...Can I use other resource file from other library(from other assemble)? I don't want create the resource file on website project.

Comment: @qakmak: Sure, you can. Just create a separate class library and add your `.resx` files there. Then reference this library in your web project. That's it. For more info, check here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778040/Beginners-Tutorial-on-Globalization-and-Localizati

Comment: You can not use this approach for localizing `PropertyValueRequired`, see [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12545997/3242721) for explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know how to eliminate the :: after the field name? If I put The filed {0} must be a num.. it will say for The field Number:: must be a num. How to remove those ::?

Answer (score 7):

you can set your custom message for your validation.

```
 [RegularExpression("\d{9}",ErrorMessage="El campo tiene que ser numerico")]
 public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
```

Comment: yep I know that way but there is not a way that i can set that for all my int insteed of doing field for field?

Comment: Yeah.I think that you do it..or create a public mask for  your control that bind to a numeric type property.Or define your property in base class if your property is a common property .

Comment: and when you try to change decimal delimeter in jquery.validate.js then you will encounter another error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify custom message for each Integer , double and float . you can use Range Attribute with String as below.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global), ErrorMessageResourceName = "YearOfEstablishmentRequired")]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global), ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValidYearOfEstablishment")]
    [Display(Name = "Year Of Establishment")]
    public string YearOfEstablishment { get; set; }
```

Now as above you can specify custom message for each and every propery .

Answer (score 0):

For those using **Razor Pages**, this code may help (should be placed in **Program.cs** or **Startup.cs**)

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBindingMessageProvider.SetValueMustBeANumberAccessor(
            _ => "Укажите численное значение!");
    });
```