# MVC 4 ignores DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

Adding a resource file to `App_GlobalResources` with a `PropertyValueRequired` key and changing `DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey` to the file name has no effect on MVC 4. The string `The {0} field is required` is never changed.
I don't want to set the resource class type and key on every required field.
Am I missing something?

**Edit:**

I've made a small modification on Darin Dimitrov's code to keep Required customizations working:

```
public class MyRequiredAttributeAdapter : RequiredAttributeAdapter
{
    public MyRequiredAttributeAdapter(
        ModelMetadata metadata,
        ControllerContext context,
        RequiredAttribute attribute
    )
        : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
        if (attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType == null)
        {
            attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages);
        }
        if (attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName == null)
        {
            attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName = "PropertyValueRequired";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is not specific to ASP.NET MVC 4. It was the same in ASP.NET MVC 3. You cannot set the required message using `DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey`, only the `PropertyValueInvalid`.

One way to achieve what you are looking for is to define a custom `RequiredAttributeAdapter`:

```
public class MyRequiredAttributeAdapter : RequiredAttributeAdapter
{
    public MyRequiredAttributeAdapter(
        ModelMetadata metadata,
        ControllerContext context,
        RequiredAttribute attribute
    ) : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
        attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Messages);
        attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName = "PropertyValueRequired";
    }
}
```

that you will register in `Application_Start`:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(
    typeof(RequiredAttribute),
    typeof(MyRequiredAttributeAdapter)
);
```

Now when a non-nullable field is not assigned a value, the error message will come from `Messages.PropertyValueRequired` where `Messages.resx` must be defined inside `App_GlobalResources`.

Comment: Perfect! I did a lot of research and found nothing similar. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar for the type validation, e.g. for dates?

Comment: We researched why you need an adapter for this: the entry GlobalResources.PropertyValueRequired is only used for non-nullable types which are not marked as "Required". The "real" Required message can only be changed using this adapter solution.

Comment: There exist `DataTypeAttributeAdapter` and `CompareAttributeAdapter` but unlike `RequiredAttributeAdapter` they are internal. What the hell?

Comment: Great answer! I will add that resx file doesn't have to be located in App_GlobalResources folder. It doesn't have to be located in the same project at all.

Comment: The derived RequiredAttributeAdapter does not seem to be called on custom datatypes, thus the metadata in the EditorTemplate does only contain the default error message. Does anyone know a solution for this?