# MVC Site Map Provider and localization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, resources, mvcsitemapprovider

I've found out today that for my site i could use a SiteMap provider which i've downloaded from Github for the MVC3, as my web application is MVC3.

Situation is following, my application is multilingual. I have a separate Library which contains all the resources. This Library is then added to my current project and everywhere where i need i use those resource files.

Now i've implemented the site map provider:

```
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:Base,Home" controller="Home" action="Index" enableLocalization="true">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Search" controller="Search" action="Index"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Contact" controller="Contact" action="Index"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About"/>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

But when i run it i get an error because it cannot find the resource with the key home. I think it is due to the fact that is outside of the application but in a separate Library.

How do i point to the resource file then, which is located din separate project?

Comment: Where have you defined your resources ? whats your class name in which you have defined these resources.?

Answer (score 4):

The approach I would take would be to switch to external DI and then implement a custom IStringLocalizer class that can read the resources from another assembly. Here is a working example. I have created a [demo application](https://github.com/NightOwl888/MvcSiteMapProvider_ExternalResources) on GitHub as well.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Resources;

namespace MvcSiteMapProvider.Globalization
{
    public class ResourceManagerStringLocalizer
        : IStringLocalizer
    {
        public ResourceManagerStringLocalizer(
            ResourceManager resourceManager
            )
        {
            if (resourceManager == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("resourceManager");
            this.resourceManager = resourceManager;
        }
        protected readonly ResourceManager resourceManager;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the localized text for the supplied attributeName.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="attributeName">The name of the attribute (as if it were in the original XML file).</param>
        /// <param name="value">The current object's value of the attribute.</param>
        /// <param name="enableLocalization">True if localization has been enabled, otherwise false.</param>
        /// <param name="classKey">The resource key from the ISiteMap class.</param>
        /// <param name="implicitResourceKey">The implicit resource key.</param>
        /// <param name="explicitResourceKeys">A <see cref="T:System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection"/> containing the explicit resource keys.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public virtual string GetResourceString(string attributeName, string value, bool enableLocalization, string classKey, string implicitResourceKey, NameValueCollection explicitResourceKeys)
        {
            if (attributeName == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("attributeName");
            }

            if (enableLocalization)
            {
                string result = string.Empty;
                if (explicitResourceKeys != null)
                {
                    string[] values = explicitResourceKeys.GetValues(attributeName);
                    if ((values == null) || (values.Length <= 1))
                    {
                        result = value;
                    }
                    else if (this.resourceManager.BaseName.Equals(values[0]))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            result = this.resourceManager.GetString(values[1]);
                        }
                        catch (MissingManifestResourceException)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                            {
                                result = value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                return value;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can inject it into your DI configuration module (StructureMap example shown, but any DI container will do).

First of all, you need to specify not to register the IStringLocalizer interface automatically by adding it to the excludeTypes variable.

```
var excludeTypes = new Type[] {
// Use this array to add types you wish to explicitly exclude from convention-based  
// auto-registration. By default all types that either match I[TypeName] = [TypeName] or 
// I[TypeName] = [TypeName]Adapter will be automatically wired up as long as they don't 
// have the [ExcludeFromAutoRegistrationAttribute].
//
// If you want to override a type that follows the convention, you should add the name 
// of either the implementation name or the interface that it inherits to this list and 
// add your manual registration code below. This will prevent duplicate registrations 
// of the types from occurring. 

// Example:
// typeof(SiteMap),
// typeof(SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy)
    typeof(IStringLocalizer)
};
```

Then provide an explicit registration of the ResourceManagerStringLocalizer (and its dependencies) instead.

```
// Configure localization

// Fully qualified namespace.resourcefile (.resx) name without the extension
string resourceBaseName = "SomeAssembly.Resources.Resource1";

// A reference to the assembly where your resources reside.
Assembly resourceAssembly = typeof(SomeAssembly.Class1).Assembly;

// Register the ResourceManager (note that this is application wide - if you are 
// using ResourceManager in your DI setup already you may need to use a named 
// instance or SmartInstance to specify a specific object to inject)
this.For<ResourceManager>().Use(() => new ResourceManager(resourceBaseName, resourceAssembly));

// Register the ResourceManagerStringLocalizer (uses the ResourceManger)
this.For<IStringLocalizer>().Use<ResourceManagerStringLocalizer>();
```

Then it is just a matter of specifying the resources appropriately. You need to start them with the Base Name (in this case `SomeAssembly.Resources.Resource1`), and then specify the key of the resource as the second argument.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="$resources:SomeAssembly.Resources.Resource1,ContactTitle" controller="Home" action="Contact"/>
```

Note that getting the BaseName right is the key to making it work. See the following MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfsz7ac5(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this:

Assuming your:

**ProjectName=MyProject**

**Folder** which contains **resources:LanguageFiles**

**Class** in which **resources** are **defined:Messaging**

then.

It should be like this I believe..I am not sure but may be it works for you:

```
`title=@MyProject.LanguageFiles.Messaging.Home'
```

(assuming Home is the resource defined in the Messaging class)

Comment: i tried this:  <mvcSiteMapNode title='@Resources.Base.Home' controller="Home" action="Index" enableLocalization="true"> but no success

Comment: The name of my project which contains the resource files is called Resources, and in there i have a .resx file called Base which has Home key

Comment: Project Name should be the main MVC project which is set as a StarUp project if you have more than one project included