# MvcSiteMapProvider Localization in an Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, mvcsitemapprovider

I localized my sitemap with the instructions provided [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178427(v=vs.100).aspx). The same way it is recommended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20344209). In my local enviroment it works perfectly. However, when I deploy my app to Azure, the resource file cannot be found. I know that the resources files inside the App_GlobalResources folder are not included in the project.dll, but I don't know how to localize my sitemap without using the resource files inside that folder. Do someone experienced the same problem and has a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, [Visual Studio doesn't setup the default settings on `App_GlobalResources` to deploy them with MVC](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/07/16/resource-files-and-asp-net-mvc-projects.aspx).

### Options

- [Implement `IStringLocalizer` yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798197/mvc-site-map-provider-and-localization#20818772) in order to provide localization from within your project or another assembly.
- Implement your own [ASP.NET 2.0 resource provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905797.aspx). See examples [here](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwdbResourceProvider/) and [here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Mar/31/Updated-ASPNET-Database-Resource-Provider).