# Is it possible to override [Required] error message Data anotation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, data-annotations

If i have a property :

```
[Required]
public string RandomProperty {get;set;}
```

If i use this property in the view and i dont fill out the Textbox for following property the following error message will show up : The Password field is required. Is it possible to override this error message in some way for ALL required fields in the app, instead of taking each of them and rewrite error Message?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538873/how-to-replace-the-default-modelstate-error-message-in-asp-net-mvc-2

Comment: Answer can be found here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545176/mvc-4-ignores-defaultmodelbinder-resourceclasskey