# MVC3 DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey namespace from another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, resources

How I can do assign in "DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey" the namespace from another project.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3156814/138071) I answer, I could solve the same problem, but in my solution I have the resource files in another project.

I probe with in code that is here, but I do not take it well

```
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "MySolution.Common.Resources.Mensajes";
```

Thank you.

Comment: I have implemented a solution for this case here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13121359/1742522